# When I have -pie- prefix nothing with CSS3pie works

Tags: css, css3pie

```
.btn {

    display: inline-block;
    height: 21px; width: 130px;
    line-height: 22px;

    background: #f9bb42; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f9bb42 0%, #f1dd38 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f9bb42), color-stop(100%,#f1dd38)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f9bb42 0%,#f1dd38 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f9bb42 0%,#f1dd38 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f9bb42 0%,#f1dd38 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f9bb42 0%,#f1dd38 100%); /* W3C */
   -pie-background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9bb42, #f1dd38); /* LOOK AT THIS EVERYBODY*/

    border: solid 1px #e99a03;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
       -moz-border-radius: 2px;
            border-radius: 2px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(51, 8, 0, 0.37);
       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(51, 8, 0, 0.37);
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(51, 8, 0, 0.37);

    position: relative;

    behavior: url(../../css/PIE.htc);
```

}

This style of my button.

Problem is strange to me. Before adding -pie-background property I could see border radius, from the moment I added -pie-background to code, I can't see or border radius, or grandient in background. Of course it's all about displaying in ie8,9...

- I'm sure that PIE.htc loads
- I have position set to relative

Comment: have you tried setting the path to PIE.htc relative to domain? It can cause problems in loading if it's set relative to a folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [linear-gradient using CSS3 PIE in IE9 not working, IE8 does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457519/linear-gradient-using-css3-pie-in-ie9-not-working-ie8-does)